# Adding the "is_hover: false;" data-option only with touch devices with Foundation visibility not working

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, typo3, typoscript

With typoscript i'm generating the Foundation top-bar menu. I want to add the "is_hover: false;" data-option to the top-bar menu only for touch devices. So when a touch device like a iPad is used on a click it opens the dorpdown subpages instead off opening the main page directly. For a normal desktop the hover still needs to work.

To do this i'm using the visibility options of Foundation like shown below.

```
<nav class="top-bar show-for-touch" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false;back_text: &laquo; Vorige">
<nav class="top-bar hide-for-touch" data-topbar>
```

Only this is not werking for the desktop (none touch) devices, as the menu is not shown. Any advise is welkom as i'm stuck on this for some time?